# sorting list of lists Python 2.7

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-2.7

To remove duplicates in list of lists (named 'povijest'), I used:
`povijest=[ list(set(x)) for x in povijest ]`
But I makes some structure problem when printed because its not sorted.
Whats the syntax when sorting lists in list of lists?

Comment: How do you want the sublists sorted?  alphabetically, or do you want to preserve the original sorting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will sort by the first element in each list

```
povijest= sorted([list(set(x)) for x in povijest ])
```

This will sort each sub-list, then sort the whole thing by the first element

```
povijest = sorted([sorted(i) for i in provijest])
```

Input

```
proviject = [['a','c','b'],['z','y','x'],['e','a']]
```

Result

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'e'], ['x', 'y', 'z']]
```

Comment: I think the OP means that it is no longer in the original order due to him using a `set`.

Comment: If that's the case then it's just `povijest=[sorted(set(x)) for x in povijest]` right?

Comment: @2rs2ts Not necessarily. Consider the list `l = [['z','x'],['b','a']]`. Your list comp will produce `[['x', 'z'], ['a', 'b']]`, whereas the second sort acts as a macro-sort and will produce `[['a', 'b'], ['x', 'z']]`

Comment: Yeah I'm aware, I forgot to @AlexThornton on that one.